# Update 1 field in a table from another field in a different table (OS400, not a 1 to 1 relationship)

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update, ibm-midrange

Im trying to update a field in a table from another field in a different table.

The table being updated will have multiple records that need updating from 1 match in the other table.

Example, i have a 1 million row sales history file. Those million records have aproximately 40,000 different sku codes, each row has a date and time stamp. Each sku will have multiple records in there.

I added a new field called MATCOST (material cost).

I have a second table containing SKU and the MATCOST.

So i want to stamp every line in table 1 with the corresponding SKU's MATCOST in table2. I cannot seem to achieve this when its not a 1 to 1 relationship.

This is what i have tried:

```
update 
  aulsprx3/cogtest2 
set 
  matcost = (select Matcost from queryfiles/coskitscog where 
  aulsprx3/cogtest2.item99 = queryfiles/coskitscog.ITEM ) 
where 
  aulsprx3/cogtest2.item99=queryfiles/coskitscog.ITEM
```

But that results in the SQL error: Column qualifier or table COSKITSCOG undefined and highlighting the q in the last reference to queryfiles/coskitscog.Item

Any idea's ?

Kindest Regards

Adam

Update: This is what my tables look like in principle. 1 Table contains the sales data, the other contains the MATCOSTS for the items that were sold. I need to update the Sales Data table (COGTEST2) with the data from the COSKITCOG table. I cannot use a coalesce statement because its not a 1 to 1 relationship, most select functions i use result in the error of multiple selects. The only matching field is Item=Item99

I cant find a way of matching multiple's. In the example we would have to use 3 SQL statements and just specify the item code. But in live i have about 40,000 item codes and over a million sales data records to update. If SQL wont do it, i suppose i'd have to try write it in an RPG program but thats way beyond me for the moment.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

[image: Tables Example]

Comment: Anyone else offer any assistance ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok this is the final SQL statement that worked. (there were actually 3 values to update)

```
    UPDATE atst2f2/SAP20 ct                                  
       SET VAL520 = (SELECT cs.MATCOST                       
                    FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs           
                    WHERE cs.ITEM = ct.pnum20),
           VAL620 = (SELECT cs.LABCOST                       
                    FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs           
                    WHERE cs.ITEM = ct.pnum20),
           VAL720 = (SELECT cs.OVRCOST                       
                    FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs           
                    WHERE cs.ITEM = ct.pnum20),             
       WHERE ct.pnum20 IN (SELECT cs.ITEM                    
                       FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Qualify the columns with [correlation names](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzc2cornm.htm).

```
UPDATE AULSPRX3/COGTEST2 A
    SET A.matcost = (SELECT matcost 
                       FROM QUERYFILES/COSKITSCOG B
                       WHERE A.item99 = B.item)
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
                   FROM QUERYFILES/COSKITSCOG C
                   WHERE A.item99 = C.item)
```

Comment: You may want to add a test in the last subselect for `A.matcost <> C.matcost`, since there is little point in updating records where the value will not change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JamesA but i get:
Result of SELECT more than one row when i run that :(

Comment: (SELECT matcost FROM QUERYFILES/COSKITSCOG B
    WHERE A.item99 = B.item)

The where clause here will result in multiple A=B because A might have 1000 repetitions of an Item because its driven by date. The item can be sold on every day for 5 years. This is what the COGTEST2 file holds. Huge amounts of sales history.

Comment: @ADAMMARSHALL You need to add the date/time filtering criteria in the subqueries.  I was merely using your example to demonstrate correlated subqueries.

Comment: @JamesA Ah right, sorry i misunderstood. There is no filtering criteria. For simplicity, i have for example a table with just 2 item codes and their cost (MATCOST) 

I have another table which holds 4 rows, 2 rows for each item with 3 fields. Item, Date, MATCOST. 

Problem is, i cant get the SQL to grab the item code from table 1 and update BOTH records in table 2. Because there are 2 matches in table 2 i get this issue. No matter what kind of select and update i do, it wont allow it. I have tried at least 5 different ways of updating it with no joy :(

Comment: @ADAMMARSHALL It would be easier to provide a solution if you updated the question with the full schema and sample data in the two tables you described in the last comment.

Comment: @JamesA ok i updated my post with the examples so you can see the data structure. Thanks for your help by the way, im rather new to this (as you can probably tell ha)

Answer (score 3):

This more compact way to do the same thing should be more efficient, eh?

```
UPDATE atst2f2/SAP20 ct                                  
   SET (VAL520, VAL620, VAL720) = 
       (SELECT cs.MATCOST, cs.LABCOST, cs.OVRCOST                      
                FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs           
                WHERE cs.ITEM = ct.pnum20)             
   WHERE ct.pnum20 IN (SELECT cs.ITEM                    
                   FROM queryfiles/coskitscog cs)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [UPDATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzupdt.htm), I'd suggest:

```
update 
  aulsprx3/cogtest2 
set 
  (matcost) = (select Matcost from queryfiles/coskitscog where 
               aulsprx3/cogtest2.item99 = queryfiles/coskitscog.ITEM)
where 
  aulsprx3/cogtest2.item99=queryfiles/coskitscog.ITEM
```

Note the braces around `matcost`.

Comment: Hi @Olaf Dietsche it doesnt like the initial comma. I just get: Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: SET.

Comment: for this i get Column qualifier or table COSKITSCOG undefined and it highlights the last reference to coskitscog.item